# How to set up clock for the STM32 Nucleo-64 with libopencm3/rtos

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, clock-speed, nucleo

I was using this [code from github](https://github.com/ve3wwg/stm32f103c8t6/blob/master/rtos/blinky/main.c) on a [blue pill](https://images.app.goo.gl/9JuKHJyWMoXXrLrm9). Now I would like to adapt it for [STM32F401 on a Nucleo-64 board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html#overview). I tried changing the GPIO to A7 and attaching an led (which lit up when I attached it to 3.3v) to GPIO A7 but it dit not seem to work.

I think the problem might be in this step:

`rcc_clock_setup_in_hse_8mhz_out_72mhz();   // Use this for "blue pill"`

because afaik this is the only step specific to the blue pill.

The blue pill has an 8MHz oscillator and [according to this](http://32.768%20kHz%20crystal%20oscillator), the Nucleo has a 32.768 kHz crystal oscillator.

Can someone please tell me how to modify this line?

I am using arm-none-eabi-gdb and make to upload code to Nucleo, as I was with blue pill.

TIA

Comment: "Nucleo 64" is just a PCB design that hosts a 64-pin STM part, it doesn't specify *which* one - what is critical here is that you have the STM32F401.  You are mistaken on the oscillators, both parts have both low and high speed internal oscillator options, the nucleo may also give you an option to receive a clock from the debugger MCU instead of using an external crystal.

Comment: @ChrisStratton link points to F4 nucleo board.

Comment: You shouldn't have to click or hover a link to know what someone is even asking

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite all of those functions as STM32F4 and STM32F1 have completely different clocks, different GPIOs . Changing GPIO pin is definitely not enough.+-

Comment: Where can I find this information?

Comment: on thew stm website - search for your micro and download the reference manual.